# How do I simulate a correlated subquery using PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I have a query for selecting above average salaries within a department

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name|| ' ' ||last_name as Name, salary, department_id
FROM EMPLOYEES o
WHERE SALARY >
  (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM EMPLOYEES i
     WHERE i.department_id=o.department_id);
```

How can I rewrite this query in PLSQL without using a sub-query?

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it in PL/SQL?

Comment: Hi, I'm  a no͞ob learning PL/SQL. I am looking for a clear explanation for how to convert syntax I understand into syntax I want to understand.

Comment: Assuming there aren't millions of departments, I'd start by loading averages for all departments into an array, then it's an easy procedural lookup for each row of your cursor FOR loop. (That's if I really had to do it in a loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you wanted the code, but first, I'm telling you the steps needed to do that.

```
 - Create a cursor for the main query
 - Create a loop to navigate that cursor
 - Execute the select avg and save the result in a variable.
 - Make an IF to compare
 - Output / save the result
```